# Classic Logic. Proof by induction.

Tags: logic

Prove that for any function $f: \{0, 1\}^k \rightarrow \{0, 1\} $ there exists the formula $\phi$ that contains only following connectives: $\{\rightarrow, 0 ( false) \}$ and variables from set $\{p_1, .., p_k\}$. $\phi$ has a such property that for any evalutaion $\rho$, $[[\phi]]_{\rho}$ = $f(\rho(p_1), .., \rho(p_k))$

My solution:

By induction on $k$

**Base Indutction**
It must be pretty simple, but I have no idea for that step.

**Step Induction**
$S = \{0,1\}^k \rightarrow \{0,1\}$
$R = \{0,1\}^{k+1} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$

Let's assume that for any function taken from $S$ exists the expected formula $\phi$ . Now, let's try to prove that for function $F$ taken from  $R$ there is a formula which satisfies expected properties.

Let's take any $F$ from $R$. Let's take such $f_0$ from $S$ that $f_0(a_1, .., a_k) = F(a_1, .., a_k, 0)$ and such $f_1$ from $R$ that $f_1(a_1, .., a_k) = F(a_1, .., a_k, 1) $ where $(a_1, .., a_k)$ is any tuple from $\{0,1\}^k$. From a induction assumption there is $\phi_0$ for function $f_0$ and $\phi_1$ for $f_1$ with expected properties.

$F(\rho(p_1), ..., \rho(p_{k+1})) = (p_{k+1} \rightarrow (f_1(\rho(p_1), .., \rho(p_k)) \rightarrow 0)) \rightarrow ((f_0(\rho(p_1), .., \rho(p_k))
\rightarrow p_{k+1}) \rightarrow 0) = (p_{k+1} \rightarrow ( \phi_1 \rightarrow 0)) \rightarrow ((\phi_0 \rightarrow p_{k+1}) \rightarrow 0) = [[\phi]]_\rho $

Please help me with a base and mark my solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the base case you can notice that there are only two function $f:\{0,1\}^0\to \{0,1\}$ which are the function that always gives $0$ (the formula for this one is really easy) and the function that always give $1$ (I'm sure you can build the formula with the connector $\to$ and $0$).

For your solution, I think it is correct but you should give a proof that your claim is true.

Comment: I cannot understand "which are the function that always gives 0". After all, $\{0,1\}^0$ is empty set, so what is an argument for $f$ in fact? 
"but you should give a proof that your claim is true". What do you mean?

Comment: @Logic yes it is empty, hence the functions have no argument. They are constant functions, the constant function 1 and the constant function 0. I mean you have to give an argument to show that $(p_{k+1} \rightarrow ( \phi_1 \rightarrow 0)) \rightarrow ((\phi_0 \rightarrow p_{k+1}) \rightarrow 0) = [[\phi]]_\rho$ is true